# unable to connect to management.azure.com from azure app service

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have an azure app service which I need to communicate to management.azure.com and I am getting below error.

Curl query I am executing from appservice kudu url is:

```
curl  -v  -X GET -H "Content-Type:application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer XXXXXXXXXX" https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{AuthToken}/resourceGroups/{ResourceGroup}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{appservicename}/slots?api-version=2019-08-01
```

> About to connect() to management.azure.com port 443 (#0)   Trying 13.86.219.80... Connection timed out Failed connect to management.azure.com:443; Connection timed out Closing connection 0curl: (7) Failed connect to management.azure.com:443; Connection timed out.

Where as I am able to communicate https://login.microsoftonline.com and get the auth token where as getting timed out for management.azure.com.

Do we have any restrictions in communicating to management.azure.com in appservices settings or firewall settings? We have enabled the proxy and able to communicate to external sites. Only facing connectivity to management.azure.com.

Can I get any help?

Comment: `{AuthToken}` should be `{SubscriptionId}`.

Comment: sorry , i am using the subscription id only.     curl -X GET -H "Content-Type:application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer {AuthToken}" https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription id}/resourceGroups/{Resourcegroup}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/azuswmyfiprod/slots?api-version=2019-08-01

Comment: Please check if you have set the [Azure App Service access restrictions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-ip-restrictions)

Comment: @rajeshdurga Have you checked the Azure App Service access restrictions? Do you still have the same issue? Any update here?